# How do I extract the output of Aasen's algorithm into a usable form?

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried implementing the algorithm in [Aasen's 1971 paper](https://sci-hub.se/https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01931804) on factorizing symmetric indefinite matrices. I've translated the code verbatim from Algol into Python, and I used the test example given in the paper. Their print-out from the test example matches mine. I've tried to extract the output into a usable form: A tridiagonal matrix `T`, a lower unit triangular matrix `L`, and a permutation `P`. The problem is that when I execute `pprint(L * T * L.T)` I get nothing like the input matrix `M`. How do I extract the output into a usable form?

Anyway, the input is:

```
⎡ -1   -0.2  0.5   0.2   -0.7⎤
⎢                            ⎥
⎢-0.2   1    -0.8   0    0.8 ⎥
⎢                            ⎥
⎢0.5   -0.8  0.4   -0.9  0.9 ⎥
⎢                            ⎥
⎢0.2    0    -0.9   1    0.5 ⎥
⎢                            ⎥
⎣-0.7  0.8   0.9   0.5   0.8 ⎦
```

The final state of `M` is the same as in the paper:

```
⎡        -1                -0.2                0.5                0.2         
⎢                                                                             
⎢       -0.7                0.8               -0.8                 0          
⎢                                                                             
⎢-0.714285714285714  1.47142857142857   2.09387755102041          -0.9        
⎢                                                                             
⎢0.285714285714286   0.388349514563107  -1.4621359223301    1.42801395041946  
⎢                                                                             
⎣-0.285714285714286  0.495145631067961  0.792828685258964  -0.340239043824701 

       -0.7      ⎤
                 ⎥
       0.8       ⎥
                 ⎥
       0.9       ⎥
                 ⎥
       0.5       ⎥
                 ⎥
 1.62752019809209⎦
```

and then finally, I attempt to convert the final state of `M` into a usable form: `L` becomes

```
⎡        1                   0                  0          0  0⎤
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎢        0                   1                  0          0  0⎥
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎢-0.714285714285714          0                  1          0  0⎥
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎢0.285714285714286   0.388349514563107          0          1  0⎥
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎣-0.285714285714286  0.495145631067961  0.792828685258964  0  1⎦
```

and `T` becomes

```
⎡ -1         -0.7               0                  0                   0      
⎢                                                                             
⎢-0.7        0.8         1.47142857142857          0                   0      
⎢                                                                             
⎢ 0    1.47142857142857  2.09387755102041   -1.4621359223301           0      
⎢                                                                             
⎢ 0           0          -1.4621359223301   1.42801395041946   -0.340239043824
⎢                                                                             
⎣ 0           0                 0          -0.340239043824701   1.627520198092

   ⎤
   ⎥
   ⎥
   ⎥
   ⎥
   ⎥
701⎥
   ⎥
09 ⎦
```

[I've removed the code because I thought it would confuse things.]

Answer (score 2):

The elements of L need to be shifted rightward. That is, this:

```
⎡        1                   0                  0          0  0⎤
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎢        0                   1                  0          0  0⎥
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎢-0.714285714285714          0                  1          0  0⎥
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎢0.285714285714286   0.388349514563107          0          1  0⎥
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎣-0.285714285714286  0.495145631067961  0.792828685258964  0  1⎦
```

needs to become this

```
⎡1          0                   0                  0          0⎤
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎢0          1                   0                  0          0⎥
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎢0  -0.714285714285714          1                  0          0⎥
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎢0  0.285714285714286   0.388349514563107          1          0⎥
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎣0  -0.285714285714286  0.495145631067961  0.792828685258964  1⎦
```

This wasn't clear from the original paper.